# How to add a column containing a single value to a csv file in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, terminal

I have a csv file with a header (first line) that looks like this

```
"Gene1","Gene2"
"G1","G2"
"G2","G8"
```

I want to add a column to this file containing number 9 so the file looks like this.
I need the column name of the new column to be "Score" and the value throughout is 9

```
"Gene1","Gene2","Score"
"G1","G2",9
"G2","G8",9
```

I tried this code with awk but it is naming column 9, I want its name to be "Score" how do I do this?

```
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '{ $(NF+1) = 9; print }' infile.csv > outfile.csv
```

How can I do this in shell? Thank you!

Comment: noted, I added a chunk of code I tried that didn't 100% work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a ternary operation to OP's current code to conditionally determine the new field value based on the current record number (`NR`):

```
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '{ $(NF+1) = (NR==1 ? "\"Score\"" : 9); print }' infile.csv
```

This generates:

```
"Gene1","Gene2","Score"
"G1","G2",9
"G2","G8",9
```

Answer (score 3):

Another shorthand `awk` solution:

```bash
awk '{print $0 "," (NR==1 ? "\"Score\"" : 9)}' file

"Gene1","Gene2","Score"
"G1","G2",9
"G2","G8",9
```

---

Or a `sed` solution:

```bash
sed '1s/$/,"Score"/;1!s/$/,9/' file

"Gene1","Gene2","Score"
"G1","G2",9
"G2","G8",9
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following `awk` code. We need to put a separate condition for 1st line to handle headers in it then rest of the lines can be added addiotnal field in current line which is `9` in value then simply print the line.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==1{print $0,"\"Score\"";next} {$(NF+1)="9"} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==1 ? $++NF="\"Score\"" : $++NF=9' file
"Gene1","Gene2","Score"
"G1","G2",9
"G2","G8",9
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -z 's/.*/&,9/mg;s/9/"Score"/' file
```

Slurp file into memory `-z` option.

Append `,9` to every line in the file.

Replace the first `9` by `"Score"`.

Answer (score -2):

only make the change in `ORS` once instead of every row : all other rows will already hit the first criteria at `OR ||` test ::

```
{m,g}awk 'NR-2 || ORS=",9\n"' FS='^$' ORS=',"Score"\n'
```

=

```
"Gene1","Gene2","Score"
"G1","G2",9
"G2","G8",9
```

you can get the same idea done just once using `OFS` instead :

```
{m,g}awk '++NF-NR || NF*=_^=OFS=",9"' FS='^$' OFS=',"Score"'
```